# prisma-nestjs-graphql always using prisma@5.0.0 to generate types

Tags: nestjs, prisma, prisma-graphql, pnpm

I have a problem with the [prisma-nestjs-graphql](https://github.com/unlight/prisma-nestjs-graphql) generator and pnpm in my monorepo project. My backend is in the following structure: `root/apps/server`

Here's an overview of my prisma dependencies and the generator:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@prisma/client": "^4.15.0",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prisma": "^4.15.0",
        "prisma-nestjs-graphql": "^18.0.2",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4"
    },
```

The problem is that when I use the command : `pnpx prisma generate`, the **prisma-nestjs-graphql** generator uses prisma **version 5.0.0** even if I have specified the version 4.15.0 and I get the following output:

```
warn Versions of prisma@5.0.0 and @prisma/client@4.15.0 don't match.
This might lead to unexpected behavior.
Please make sure they have the same version.
```

I think it's a problem with pnpm which must use cache or something, here's the detailed output of the location where the generator saves a folder and temporary files in pnpm :

```
../../../../../../../AppData/Local/pnpm/store/v3/tmp/dlx-13616/node_modules/.pnpm
/prisma@5.0.0/node_modules/prisma: 
Running preinst../../../../../../../AppData/Local/pnpm/store/v3/tmp/dlx-13616/node_modules/.pnpm/prisma@5.0.0/node_modules/prisma: 
Running preinstall script, done in 118ms
```

*As you can see, he uses the prisma@5.0.0 version*

I tried deleting the pnpm store, the node_modules, the pnpm-lock.yaml file, the node_modules of the /server project, and also the pnpm_cache folder in my pc, and reinstalling everything, but it didn't change anything.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can tell pnpm to always use a specific version of a package. You can add a `pnpmfile.js` at the root of your project with the following content:

```js
module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    readPackage(packageJson) {
      if (packageJson.name === 'prisma-nestjs-graphql') {
        packageJson.dependencies.prisma = '^4.15.0';
      }
      return packageJson;
    },
  },
};
```

This file tells pnpm to always use Prisma 4.15.0 for `prisma-nestjs-graphql`, overriding the version specified in its `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it didn't work I also tried renaming the file to .pnpmfile.cjs but the generator still uses prisma version 5.0.0 using `pnpx prisma generate`. However, your answer opened my eyes to other solutions, and I managed to solve the problem by using the command: `npx` instead of `pnpx`. Now it's using version 4.15.0 and not 5.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I am glad to hear that answer was somewhat helpful! :)